# Query AQL syntax required for following JSON structure

Tags: database, collections, nosql, arangodb, aql

I have a JSON structure like this

```
{
  "Items": {
     "Apple": {
       "Type": 2,
       "keyVal": "6044e3a3-c064-4171-927c-2440e2f65660"
     },
     "Lemons": {
       "Type": 1,
       "keyVal": "79c45f4d-4f62-4c8e-8de1-79e04fc9b95d"
     }
  },
  "Species": 0,
  "Name": "Test Fruit",
  "Description": "Test Des",
  "Creator": "xyz",
  "SKey" : "123"
}
```

This is present in a collection named Fruits.

Query:
I am trying to write and AQL query to find the SKey where KeyVal value in Items is some value.

I am traditionally used to the SQL syntax but this is the first time I am venturing into the AQL(Arango DB).

Any help with the Syntax is appretiated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basics of AQL are explained here really well: https://docs.arangodb.com/3.11/aql/

```
FOR item IN Items FILTER item.keyVal == "someValue" RETURN item
```

Would be your minimal SQL `SELECT ... WHERE` statement.

BTW: There is a comparative introduction to be found here:
https://arangodb.com/why-arangodb/sql-aql-comparison/

A good way to learn AQL is to try small pieces of code an return the result for inspection, to gradually create more complex queries.

For example, let's return one of the nested keyVal values:

```
FOR doc IN Fruits
  RETURN doc.Items.Apple.keyVal
  // "6044e3a3-c064-4171-927c-2440e2f65660"
```

To filter by Apple keyVal and return SKey, you can do:

```
FOR doc IN Fruits
  FILTER doc.Items.Apple.keyVal == "6044e3a3-c064-4171-927c-2440e2f65660"
  RETURN doc.SKey
  // "123"
```

You can return both keyVal values too:

```
FOR doc IN Fruits
  RETURN [
    doc.Items.Apple.keyVal,
    doc.Items.Lemons.keyVal
  ]
  // [
  //   "6044e3a3-c064-4171-927c-2440e2f65660",
  //   "79c45f4d-4f62-4c8e-8de1-79e04fc9b95d"
  // ]
```

To return SKey if either is equal to some value, try this:

```
FOR doc IN Fruits
  FILTER "79c45f4d-4f62-4c8e-8de1-79e04fc9b95d" IN [
    doc.Items.Apple.keyVal,
    doc.Items.Lemons.keyVal
  ]
  RETURN doc.SKey
```

Note: `IN` is used here as array operator, like is {value} contained in {array}.

To return all keyVal values hardcoding the attribute paths, you can make use of the [ATTRIBUTES() AQL function](https://docs.arangodb.com/3.11/aql/functions/document-object/#attributes):

```
FOR doc IN Fruits
  FOR attr IN ATTRIBUTES(doc.Items)
    RETURN doc.Items[attr].keyVal
```

To return SKey if any of the nested keyVal values match, we can do:

```
FOR doc IN Fruits
  LET keyVals = (FOR attr IN ATTRIBUTES(doc.Items)
    RETURN doc.Items[attr].keyVal
  )
  FILTER "6044e3a3-c064-4171-927c-2440e2f65660" IN keyVals
  RETURN doc.SKey
```

Note: this uses a subquery to capture the intermediate result.

To test if all specified values are contained, you could do:

```
LET ids = [
  "79c45f4d-4f62-4c8e-8de1-79e04fc9b95d",
  "6044e3a3-c064-4171-927c-2440e2f65660"
]
FOR doc IN Fruits
  LET keyVals = (FOR attr IN ATTRIBUTES(doc.Items)
    RETURN doc.Items[attr].keyVal
  )
  FILTER ids ALL IN keyVals
  RETURN doc.SKey
```

[ALL IN](https://docs.arangodb.com/3.11/aql/operators/#array-comparison-operators) is an array comparison operator.

Note that it would require a change to your data model if you wanted to use indexes without hardcoding the attributes paths, and also different queries.

Comment: @CoDmanX  thank you very much. This explanation is very thorough and extremely helpful. I got a nice overview for AQL and the links posted are also helpful. Thank you very much

Comment: he just cut + pasted the documentation here :))))

Comment: still it is very thorough and you added a personal touch on the queries which helped me understand

Comment: @KavehVahedipour Love you too 